# How to match with "\*" but not with "/\*" in Regex?

Tags: regex

I need to match all the `*` in a txt, but not when the `*` is preceded by a `/`.

I have tried with: `[^/]\*`

But when match, it matches with  `*` and not with `*`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is exactly what negative lookbehind is for. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Negative Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which allows you to match an expression not preceeded by another expression.

```
(?<!\/)\*
```

Working example here: https://regex101.com/r/inA6Ql/1

[image]